# Set class dynamically according to array values in Angular 2

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I'm new with TypeScript and Angular 2 and I didn't know how to solve it.

I have an array of week days and a frequency array of seven numbers, or 0 or 1, and each '1' correspond to a day of the week, so Monday will be [1,0,0,0,0,0,0], Saturday and Sunday will be [0,0,0,0,0,1,1] and so on.
The arrays are dynamic, because the frequency array arrived from a server.

For each '1' I have to append a class, but if I have two consecutive 1 each of these will have two different classes, if I have three consecutive 1 the centered one will also has a class different from the others two, and if the 1 is 'alone' it will have another class too.

For example, if the array is

```
frequencyArray: number[] = [1,0,1,1,1,0,0]
```

the first 1 must have the class 'singleOne', the second 1 must have the class 'leftOne', the third 'centerOne' and the four 'rightOne'.

Now in the HTML I have

```
<span *ngFor="let frequency of frequencies; let i = index" [ngClass]="{'singleOne' : frequency}">{{weekDays[i]}}</span>
```

So he append the 'singleOne' class to every 1 in the `frequencyArray`.
How can I change it dynamically according to the position of the numbers?

I hope to have explained it well.

Comment: If you have three in a row, you've said it should be ['leftOne', 'centerOne', 'leftOne'], which seems a bit odd. What happens if all of the frequencies are 1? Should it be ['leftOne', 'centerOne', 'centerOne', 'centerOne', 'centerOne', 'centerOne', 'leftOne']?

Comment: And to be honest, the answer is just to create a new array, loop through the `frequencyArray`, and for each element, check if it's 1. If it is, look at the previous one and the next one, and push the appropriate class name into the array. Then just use `[ngClass]="classNames[i]"`.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I'm sorry, I mean that if I have three consecutive 1 (and not only in a row) it should be leftOne, centerOne, rightOne. So I have to check not only if there are 1 and take the previous and the next one, but also check if they are near, because if they are 'alone' the class would be 'singleOne'. Anyway my problem is to write this because I'm learning, so if you can write me how to do it will be great :D

Comment: Getting the previous and next would tell you what you need to know. If the previous element was also a 1, and the next element is a 1, make it "centerOne". If the previous element is a 1 and the next element is a 0 (or there is no next element), then make it "rightOne". If the previous element is a 0 (or there is no previous element) and the next element is a 1, make it "leftOne". If both the previous and the next are both 0 (or one is 0 and the other doesn't exist), make it "singleOne". If the current element is a 0, don't write anything.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan yes, you're right. But how can I wrote this? Can you help me? I'm learning the code.

Comment: I really believe you'll learn better if you try and do it yourself, rather than having me or someone else write it for you. I've given you the entire algorithm; you should be able to translate that, line by line, into code.

Comment: I don't want to seem hasty, but I checked and checked for about three hours, this is why I asked here, and because I'm learning coding I can't learn alone if nobody say to me how to write my ideas. Anyway thank you very much for your help :) @MikeMcCaughan